# QT qml image orientation

Tags: android, image, qt, qml, orientation

I'm trying to build an app using Qt for android.
I wrote a very simple code to help in my question.

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
ApplicationWindow {
  property string imagePath: "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/camera/20180910_141351.jpg"
  visible: true
  Image {
    id: picture
    anchors.fill: parent
    fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
    source: "file://" + imagePath
  }
}
```

I'm trying to add an image from my mobile to the application, the problem I'm facing is the following:

1. if the image is taken by the camera, the image is shown rotated inside the app (if it's originally portrait it's shown as landscape and vice versa)
2. if the image is not taken by the camera, for example saved from the web, it shown correctly.

Is there a way I can fix this automatically via qml? or do I have to rotate the image by code?

Also, if I have to write a code to do the rotation, how can I know the orientation of the image? please note that in some cases I may have a list of images, so I'll need rotate all of them.

Comment: Have you tried to play with the `autoTransform`-property? (Just an idea, I don't know whether it works)

Comment: Damn, that was easy. Thank you, it solved the issue